# Reportlab multiple column table layout alignment

Tags: python, reportlab

I am trying to build a simple table with two columns using Reportlab in python.
The problem is that starting rows are not lined up properly if number of rows are not equal.

For example, I need this:

```
Desc1  Desc2
aaa   ddd
bbb   eee
ccc
```

However, I get this:

```
Desc1  Desc2
aaa   
bbb   ddd
ccc   eee
```

Here is my code:

```
 flowables = []
 col2_data = []
 for i, row in df.iterrows():
    desc1 = row['desc_1']
    desc2 = row['desc_2']
    col2_data.append([desc1, desc2])

 col1_data = [[Paragraph('aaa', styles['Normal'])], 
            [Paragraph('bbb', styles['Normal'])],
            [Paragraph('ccc', styles['Normal'])]
            ]
 t = Table(col1_data, colWidths=[200])

 # Create the table for col2_data
 col2_table_data = [[Paragraph(f'{desc1} x {desc2}', styles['Normal'])] for qty, desc in col2_data]

 col2_table = Table(col2_table_data, colWidths=[300])
 combined_table_data = [[t, col2_table]]
 combined_table = Table(combined_table_data, colWidths=[200, 300])

 flowables.append(combined_table)
```